# Print inside a star pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way in this code that I can print some input inside the equilateral triangle?
I've tried several way but it seems to be not working. It just prints on all whitespaces.

```
h=int(input("Enter Height: "))
for r in range(1, h+1):
    for c in range(1, 2*h):
        if r==h or r+c==h+1 or c-r==h-1:
            print("*", end="")
        else:
            print(end =" ")   
    print()
```

the output now is this:

[image: OUTPUT]

and i want to print inside:

[image: WHAT I WANT TO DO]

example:
[image: Example]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you want to achieve. Perhaps a sample input and output would be helpful

Comment: i edit the post with jpg

Comment: Put it in the question, not a comment.

Comment: I am pretty sure you would have to compute the width of the triangle and of the text you want to print inside, and then print the word at the time where you would otherwise have printed whitespace characters

Comment: Could you provide some sample output? Not an image - some text that your finished script would actually produce

Comment: You can print in the middle when `c` is between `h+1-r` and `h-1+r`.

Comment: If you solved it, post your code as an answer.

Comment: @barmar it worked only for one letter string, if i put digit to print in the middle more it dose`nt work it move all the row`s a side

Comment: You an increment an index, or use `iter()` as in the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

That should be a good starting point for you:

```
h=int(input("Enter Height: "))
characters = iter("word")
for r in range(1, h+1):
    for c in range(1, 2*h):
        if r==h or r+c==h+1 or c-r==h-1:
            print("*", end="")
        elif r==(h*2)//3 and c > h+2-r and c < h-2+r:
            try:
                print(next(characters), end="")
            except StopIteration:
                print(end = " ")
        else:
            print(end =" ")   
    print()
```

You need to compute the range in which it is okay to print your word, and print it there. In order to keep track of the characters that you already printed, you can use an [iterator](https://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html) as I did on the second line here.

I have used arbitrary values here for limiting the range. I think you can figure the rest out on your own easily enough.

[image: sample output]

Comment: Use `elif` rather than nested `if`.

Comment: That's a detail, but sure. Feel free to edit my answer so that it becomes beautiful code